# Thymeleaf Switch-Case, Embedding Classes and Secondary Variables

Tags: java, spring, thymeleaf

For some reason despite online examples, I can't seem to get classes to embed within tags when using div th :switch= "$(some_var)", even though it works for a th:if.

Further, I know this will be a syntax/regex issue. I just can't seem to crack how to embed a secondary variable in the id attribute, which is really needed for clicking functionality. Please help. Here's the code I have. Basically, it should create a table of data dynamically brought in from the template engine.

```
<th:block th:each="workflow : ${workflows}">

     <div th:switch="${workflow.status}">
          <tr th:case="'Accepted'" class="accepted">
          <tr th:case="'Declined'" class="declined">
          <tr th:case="'Pushed Back'" class="pushed-back">
          <tr th:case="'Approved'" class="lock"></tr>
          <tr th:case="null" id="confirm_$(workflow.id)_row">
     </div>

     <td th:text="${workflow.name}">Test Name</td>
     //...
     <th:block th:if="${workflow.status} == null">
          <td class="confirm" id="confirm_$(workflow.id)">
              <b>Confirm</b>
          </td>
     </th:block>
     <th:block th:unless="${conversation_holder} != null">
          <td id="confirm_$(workflow.id)">
              <b>Confirm</b>
          </td>
     </th:block>
  </tr>
</th:block>
```

id="confirm_$(workflow.id)" comes out as-typed instead of having a numeric be embedded after the underscore. It should be "confirm_123456" instead. And is there an additional trick to embedding this value between two bits of text, such as the final tr case?

Answer (score 1):

First, one of the principles of thymeleaf is that even the template are valid html.  This isn't like jsp or php, where you can have multiple opening `<tr>` tags for a single `</tr>` tag, or a `<div>` in the middle of your tables -- or at least you shouldn't.

It's kind of hard to recommend without seeing the entire table, but I don't think a switch is a good fit in this case.  I would probably just use `if`s.  In the specific case of the `class` attribute, you might consider adding a helper java method `workflow.htmlClass` or naming the css classes differently so you can lowercase `workflow.status` and replace space with -.

Second, If you want thymeleaf to evaluation an attribute, it must be prefixed with `th:` ([and be an attribute supported by thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#setting-value-to-specific-attributes)).

```
id="confirm_$(workflow.id)_row"
```

Should be

```
th:id="${'confirm_' + workflow.id + '_row'}"
```

There are other ways to do string concatenation as well, so use whatever syntax you like best.

Comment: The problem with not using Switch is I have 7 conditions (the page needs to be self-reporting and display via color coded rows the actions downstream post-approval) for specific user types. Thanks so much for the th:id attribute notation though. That's not something well-documented in the thymeleaf project tutorial site, or anywhere really.

Comment: Right, and I've offered a couple of solutions instead of a switch. 1: Matching class names more closely with the status, so you can just do `th:class="${workflow.status}"`, or adding a getStatusClass() method that returns the css class for a specified status: `th:class="${workflow.statusClass}"`.  You can of course use th:switch, but you will have to do a lot of html duplication.

Comment: I'm going ahead with the class matching, and definitely thanks for that. It just seems like a terrible shortcoming in Thymeleaf's flexibility.